# How to look at multiple map ranges in google sheets

Tags: dictionary, textjoin, hstack

I was getting help from someone but they are no longer replying to messages.

With the following formaula, I can't work out how to add in an additional map range without getting a filter error shown below. Right now it's only looking at **'TAB1'!L:L**, needing help to include **'TAB1'!Q:Q**.

*FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 523. column count: 1. Actual row count: 1, column count: 1.*

=sort(filter(hstack('TAB1'!B:C,ifs(regexmatch('TAB1'!L:L,textjoin("|",1,Events!G:G)),"YES",regexmatch('TAB1'!L:L,'TAB1'!Q:Q,textjoin("|",1,Events!H:H)),"NO",1,)),'TAB1'!A:A=A1,regexmatch(A2,map('TAB1'!L:L,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,textjoin("|",1,index(if(len(offset(Σ,,1,,4)),Σ&" "&offset(Σ,,1,,4),)))))))),3,)

Is my worksheet, and working from the **Help** tab.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GjG7aVw4nsQL_2Iag6q22aQuFXXdzqq_B1BRWkwhmI8/edit#gid=887902153

Trying to have to ranges being looked at not just one. Right now it's only looking at 'TAB1'!L:L but I need 'TAB1'!L:L and 'TAB1'!Q:Q